# Keycloak Access token

Tags: java, mysql, keycloak

I have set up Keycloak-5.0.0 with Spring Boot Application using MySQL database. So, my question is where does it store the Access Token?

I have checked all the tables in the database but none of them have it and I even checked the keycloak-5.0.0 code in case it stores it in some files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your setup the resource server doesn't store tokens at all. Keycloak has a database for the users it knows, of course. Then you have a client application which uses the tokens (access token, refresh token etc.) to speak with the resource server on the user's behalf. In case of a web application you might store the tokens in the local storage of your browser to survive a reload or just hold them in RAM as @BorislavStoilov wrote.

The resource server (if configured as bearer only) will usually fetch the current public key from keycloak from time to time to validate the tokens with each request but will not store them.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in the ram, at least the data needed to validate them.
Only offline tokens are stored in database.